# Complex SecRule that matches more than one thing

Tags: apache, mod-security2

I'm a newbie using mod_security2. I have only being using it for about 3 weeks.

Hope someone can tell me how to accomplish the following.
I'm looking for a way to create a rule that:

1. If the url, after the domain name begins with `/SOMETHING`
2. And the argument name (contains anywhere `date` or `timestamp`) or (is exactly `lastLogon`)
3. And the argument value matches the regex `^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}[-+]?[0-9]{4}$`
4. Or the argument name is exactly "filters" (no matter what value it has)
5. Then do ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173

What I think the [Reference Manual](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual) is missing, is an explained complex example of SecRule. Maybe I just couldn't find it, in which case, please forgive me and please point me in the right direction.

I'm using version 2.9.0

Maybe using [chain](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#chain) or something like that?. Couldn't make it work (because of the needed boolean `or`). I don't know.

Since I'm already writing this request for help, maybe there is a shortcut it would be handy to know: I have many rules to write that apply if the url after the domain name begins with `/SOMETHING`, Is there an easy way to handle them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I added [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35903148/2796922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working rules are:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /SOMETHING" \
        "phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173;ARGS:filters,id:'10000'"

SecRule ARGS:/(?i)^.*date.*$/|ARGS:/(?i)^.*timestamp.*$/|ARGS:/(?i)^lastLogin$/ \
        "@rx ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}[-+]?[0-9]{4}$" \
        "phase:2,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,id:'10010'"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /SOMETING" "ctl:ruleRemoveById=981173"
```

The problem i'm facing now is that the phase 2 one is not executed in my `modsecurity_crs_15_customrules.conf` configuration file, it only gets executed if it is placed in `modsecurity.conf`.

I'm still looking for a definitive solution for this new problem. (see: [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35903148/2796922))

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out how to do it.

```
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /SOMETHING" "phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173;ARGS:filters,id:'10000'"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /SOMETHING" "phase:1,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveById=981173,id:'10010'"
        SecRule ARGS:/(?i)^.*date.*$/|ARGS:/(?i)^.*timestamp.*$/|ARGS:lastLogon "@rx ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}[-+]?[0-9]{4}$" "t:none"
```

Am I right?
Any Comments?

Comment: This will not work. You can only check one thing at a time and your first rule checks ARGS in the action section which is not correct (hence need for Chained Rules). Second rule might work though though you shouldn't do the ctl action until the second part of the chain is passed too - otherwise this would be called after first part of the chain matches.

Comment: I guess I will have to test it further, since it start's without error, and it stopped showing 403 errors after adding those rules. Thank's for pointing it out.

Comment: You can find [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#chain) : "The disruptive actions specified in the first portion of the chained rule will be triggered only if all of the variable checks return positive hits" So I think there should be no problem with the chained rule.(I hope)

Comment: As per comment below ctl is a non-disruptive: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ctl

Comment: Wow, I guess you're right... so... In which of the rules after the first one should I put the ctl rule? Does it matter?

Comment: Hello @BazzaDP. About your first comment. I was sure I took the syntax like the first rule from somewhere and now I found it. From the same link you gave me... the second example has this exact syntax   ([https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ctl](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ctl)). So that one should work. Right?

Comment: Ah you are correct. The ARGS is an argument to ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById rather than an extra action. Mistook the semi-colon for a comma. Apologies. So your first rule will work. But your second will not as you should put that ctrl action in the last rule in the chain and not the first one.

Comment: That's what I'm trying... but never matches... the level 9 debug log says the fist row (without the ctl now) do match, but the second doesn't. What I'm missing in the logs is any indication that which argument names where tested against...

Comment: So first rule works? And second rule in two parts only half works? Syntax for the chained rule should be something like this "SecRule ARGS:/(?i)^.*date.*$/|/(?i)^.*timestamp.*$/|^lastLogon$". I.e. only specific ARGS once and then a regexp that will match the value of that.

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work that way: `Error creating rule: Unknown variable: /(?i)^.*timestamp.*$/`

Comment: Also tried `SecRule ARGS:"/(?i)^.*date.*$|^.*timestamp.*$|^lastLogon$/"` with almost the same result: `Error creating rule: Unknown variable: ^.*timestamp.*$`

Comment: I'd suggest taking it back a step rather than trying to solve it all in one complicated chained rule first of. Either split it into 3 sets of chained rules or write a rule just to match second chain and do nothing but log. Once you've figured that out and got it matching you can look to combine into one chained rule again. Simplicity always rules! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105830/discussion-between-elysch-and-bazzadp).

Answer (score 0):

Finding it difficult to understand exactly what you are wanting.

It may be possible to write one chained rule for all that but probably easier and more readable to write several rules.

I would suggest you look at [REQUEST_URI](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#REQUEST_URI) which contains the requested resource and parameters.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/SOMETHING.*\?(.*&)+(.*date.*|.*timestamp.*|lastLogon)=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}[-+]?[0-9]{4}(&.*)+$" "id=12345,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173"
```

And then a separate rule for your other one:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/SOMETHING.*\?(.*&)+(filters)=.*" "id=12346,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173"
```

The last rule could also be written as:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "^/SOMETHING.*" "id=12346,chain"
    ARGS "^filters$" "ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981173"
```

As to your other requirement, you could set a variable when the REQUEST_FILENAME matches SOMETHING and then check that each time. But probably just as easy to do the check each time through a chained rule last last code snippet above.

Comment: I don't particularly like the first code you wrote. It wouldn't guarantee the words `date`, `timestamp` and `lastLogon` correspond to arguments. It could happen that those substrings match in other contexts.

Comment: About the "chained" example... I tried something very similar before but didn't work, since `ctl` rules aren't allowed after the first row.

Comment: Yeah it's a fair point on the arguments though the question mark ensures they are either arguments or argument values. You'll know your app better to know if that's sufficient but understand your concerns. You could add more chains to test they are arguments.

Comment: Ctl rules are allowed after the first row AFAIK as they are classified as non-disruptive: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ctl